# Gitlab CI dependency on release or debug build

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I am learning how gitlab-runner works, and creating a script for running builds for a windows C# project.

I setup a runner on my shell and installed all the needed tools to build, but now I am at the step that I need to create a good .yml script to run.

I already have some code but I don't know if it is possible to have **multiple dependencies like an OR**?

**This is the way I want to set it up:**
[image: The steps]

This is what I have for now:

```
variables:
  PROJECT_LOCATION: "ProjectFolder"
  PROJECT_NAME: "ProjectName"

before_script:
  - echo "starting build for %PROJECT_NAME%"
  - cd %PROJECT_LOCATION%

stages:
  - build
  - artifacts
  - test
  - deploy

build:debug:
  stage: build
  script:
  - echo "Restoring NuGet Packages..."
  - 'nuget restore "%PROJECT_NAME%.sln"'
  - echo "Starting debug build..."
  - 'msbuild /consoleloggerparameters:ErrorsOnly /maxcpucount /nologo /property:Configuration=Debug /verbosity:quiet /p:AllowUnsafeBlocks=true /nr:false "%PROJECT_NAME%.sln"'
  except:
    - master
  tags:
    - windows

build:release:
  stage: build
  script:
  - echo "Restoring NuGet Packages..."
  - 'nuget restore "%PROJECT_NAME%.sln"'
  - echo "Starting release build..."
  - 'msbuild /consoleloggerparameters:ErrorsOnly /maxcpucount /nologo /property:Configuration=Release /verbosity:quiet /p:AllowUnsafeBlocks=true /nr:false "%PROJECT_NAME%.sln"'
  only:
    - master
  tags:
    - windows

artifacts:
  stage: artifacts
  script:
  - echo "Creating artifacts..."
  dependencies: 
    - build
  artifacts:
    name: "Console"
    paths:
      - Project.Console/bin/
    expire_in: 2 days
    untracked: true

    name: "Service"
    paths:
       - Project.Service/bin/
    expire_in: 1 week
    untracked: true
  only:
    - tags
    - master
    - schedules
  tags:
    - windows

test:unit:
  stage: test
  script:
  - echo "Running tests..."
  dependencies: 
    - build
  tags:
    - windows

test:integration:
  stage: test
  script:
  - echo "Running integration tests..."
  dependencies: 
    - build
  only:
    - tags
    - master
    - schedules
  tags:
    - windows

deploy:
  stage: deploy
  script:
  - echo "Deploy to production..."
  dependencies: 
    - build
  environment:
    name: production
  only:
    - tags
  tags:
    - windows
```

But as you can see I give it the **dependency build and it doesn't like this because I have build:debug and build:release. Is there a way to get around this?**

If there are other pointers I need to keep in mind always welcome... (Like I said I am still learing)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer apparently you can have multiple dependencies and this is an or statement.

So for example:

```
artifacts:
  stage: artifacts
  script:
  - echo "Creating artifacts..."
  dependencies: 
    - build:debug
    - build:release
  artifacts:
    name: "Console"
    paths:
      - Project.Console/bin/
    expire_in: 2 days
    untracked: true

    name: "Service"
    paths:
       - Project.Service/bin/
    expire_in: 1 week
    untracked: true
  only:
    - tags
    - master
    - schedules
  tags:
    - windows
```